# LocalStorage button & list

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm pretty new to Javascript.

I need a "Add to favorites/remove from favorites" function on several products pages. The function would save the product id and put it in a array.

And then, I need to write a page that retrieve all the products id's from LocalStorage in order to display them with a MYSQL select.

I've got the MYSQL part covered but can you help me a bit with the Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to show some programming effort, at the bare minimum. Oh... Welcome to Stack Overflow!!!

Comment: add your what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you can declare array of ids

```
var favourites = new Array();
```

then in your code you should add items to this array

```
favourites.push('file1_id')
favourites.push('file2_id')
```

At the end save it to localstorage (stringify array to json, you have to store strings in LocalStorage)

```
localStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(favourites))
```

On page where you do the SQL query you can get saved ids from LocalStorage (parse JSON so you get the original array)

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favourites'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this is what I ended with...

```
var abbeysList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('abbeys'));
var index = abbeysList.indexOf(<?php echo $id; ?>);
var favs = document.getElementById("favs");
document.getElementById("favs").onclick = function() {changeClass()};
if (index>-1) {

favs.className += " active";    
}        

if (index == -1) {

favs.className += " inactive";


}   

function changeClass() {

if(document.getElementById('favs').classList.contains("inactive")) {  

document.getElementById("favs").className = "active";
abbeysList.push(<?php echo $id; ?>);
localStorage.setItem('abbeys', JSON.stringify(abbeysList)); 

}else {  

document.getElementById("favs").className = "inactive";  
abbeysList.splice(index, 1);
localStorage.setItem('abbeys', JSON.stringify(abbeysList));   

}  


}
```